# How to pass a Method/ThreadStart to a Base Constructor in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, inheritance

I'm currently working with a class named *Engine* that's designed to accept a *ThreadStart* delegate in its constructor. Here's a simplified version of the *Engine* class:

```
public class Engine {
    public Engine(ThreadStart threadStart) {
        // Initialization logic here...
    }
}
```

My goal is to extend this class with another class called *UpdateEngine*. Unlike *Engine*, *UpdateEngine* does not directly take a *ThreadStart* in its constructor. Instead, it has a method named *UpdateRun* that I wish to pass as the *ThreadStart* to the *Engine*'s constructor, like so:

```
public class UpdateEngine : Engine {
    public UpdateEngine() : base(UpdateRun) {
        // Additional initialization logic here...
    }

    public void UpdateRun() {
        // Method implementation...
    }
}
```

However, when I attempt this, I encounter a compiler error: *CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.*

I understand that there are various ways to tackle method inheritance and overriding (e.g., using *virtual*, *override*, *abstract* or *static*), but I'm curious if there's a way to achieve my goal using this particular approach.

I've also experimented with introducing a delegate type (e.g., *CallBack*) in the *Engine* class and using it as a parameter for the constructor, but that didn't pan out either.

Does anyone have insights or suggestions on how this can be accomplished? Any guidance or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `UpdateRun` would need to be static to be passed as a delegate in the constructor.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? `ThreadStart` is a delegate type, not a thread, and you just *don't* need it. You can pass an `Action<T,...>` (a more modern delegate type) and run it with `Task.Run`. Whetehr that's a good idea or not depends on what you want to do

Comment: As mentioned earlier, instance members can not be passed to the base constructor. Instead, you can make that method virtual (or abstract) in the base class and override it in the derived classes.

Comment: Also, typically one does not use a ThreadStart or Action argument to a base class, but use an overridable method that is called by the thread of the base class. (eg. move `UpdateRun` to the base class and make it virtual)

Comment: Just a thought, but you might be better off with composition. Extract a common interface and then implement it by wrapping an instance of the base type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done unless `public void UpdateRun()` is made `static`, which kind of defeats the purpose.

This is happening because the base class constructors are invoked before the constructor of the current class executes, which means that while invoking base class constructors, there is no `this` pointer, and therefore you cannot access anything that belongs to the current instance.

This snag is encountered in all object-oriented languages, (it is not specific to C++,) and it has no solution: you have to re-arrange the structure of your classes in order to get past it.

Comment: I want to make sure I've got this right. I can't achieve this because the UpdateEngine class and its methods/variables, specifically UpdateRun(), don't exist at the time I invoke the base() argument?

I know that my approach might not be the best way to accomplish my goal. I understand that using override, abstract, virtual, or similar techniques would be more appropriate. This inquiry was mainly driven by my curiosity; I wanted to understand why my initial approach didn't work.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  `UpdateRun()` does not exist at the time you invoke `base()`. To put it differently, `UpdateRun()` is only meaningful when `this` exists, and `this` does not yet exist when invoking `base()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mike! That was exactly the information I needed.